# How to convert Calendar to JSON

Tags: java, angularjs, json, rest

I'm development a rest application like this

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_verarq")
public class Verificacao implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "ultima_verificacao")      
    private Calendar dataHoraUltimaVerificacao;
}
```

On XML will see this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <verificacao>
  <dataHoraUltimaVerificacao>2017-04-04T20:57:46.490-03:00</dataHoraUltimaVerificacao> 
  <id>1</id> 
  </verificacao>
```

But in my web page only appears a number

[image]

**update**
this is my Angular

```
var professoresModulo = angular.module('arquivocopemModulo',[]);

professoresModulo.controller("arqcopem-controller", function($scope,$http){

    urlVerificacao="http://localhost:8080/monitoriabnb/rest/verificacaocopem";

    $scope.buscaVerificacao  = function (){
        $http.get(urlVerificacao).success(function(verificacao) {
            console.log(verificacao);
            $scope.verificacao = verificacao;
        }).error(function(erro) {
            alert(erro);
        });
    }


    $scope.buscaVerificacao();


});
```

I try this but don't work either

```
$scope.verificacao.dataHoraUltimaVerificacao = Date.parse($scope.verificacao.dataHoraUltimaVerificacao);
```

I try to convert with Angular but don't work 
any suggestions for me?

Comment: show us your angular code - show us the view code, and the rest call from angular

Answer (score 0):

Try using momentjs which handles DATE TIME efficiently. You can modify your code as below

```
$scope.verificacao.dataHoraUltimaVerificacao = moment($scope.verificacao.dataHoraUltimaVerificacao, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').toDate();
```

You can as well convert to custom format by extracting date, month , year, hours, minutes etc using moment functions.

```
var dd = $scope.verificacao.dataHoraUltimaVerificacao.getDate();
var mm = $scope.verificacao.dataHoraUltimaVerificacao.getMonth();
var yy = $scope.verificacao.dataHoraUltimaVerificacao.getUTCFullYear();

return ((dd) + "/" + (mm+1) + "/" + yy);
```

I hope this helps....